# DocuSign demo account Integrator Key connect to Customer DocuSign accounts

Tags: c#, docusignapi

My question is currently I have a demo sandbox account with integrator key used to send documents to DocuSign. All my clients have their own DocuSign production accounts is it possible for me to connect my Demo integrator Key with clients DocuSign accounts? Also going into production environment do I need to get a DocuSign licensing to use my integrator key with other accounts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an integrator key goes Live and is promoted to the Production environment, it is linked to a single account for management purposes, but it can be used with any DocuSign account.

You will need a DocuSign account on an API plan or Enterprise-level account to complete key promotion, but there's no special/additional licensing to enable a key to be used with other accounts once it is live.

Comment: Suppose we have a SaaS app that stores files and we want end-customers that have a paid DocuSign account to integrate. This means we need to pay for our own API account, even if it's our customers who are paying DocuSign? Is this correct? Even if we only allowed existing DocuSign customers to use it, it would make no difference in our own cost?

Comment: Sounds like you may qualify for a free ikey holding account via the DocuSign Partners program. I'd recommend reaching out to partners@docusign.com to learn more.